# Creating mesh from custom source with VTK.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, vtk, vtk.js

I'm trying to display a mesh in a react ts app using `@kitware/vtk.js 18.1.2` and a custom source.

First I created a working scene with a cone source:

```
// (...)
const coneSource = vtkConeSource.newInstance();

const mapper = vtkMapper.newInstance();
// @ts-ignore
mapper.setInputConnection(coneSource.getOutputPort());
// (...)
```

And it works as expected, despite functions like `setInputConnection` and `getOutputPort` not being declared (that's why I used `@ts-ignore`).

Now I'm trying to display my own data by creating a custom `vtkPolyData`.
[There are tutorials in the documentation of vtk.js](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1Sr1OGxMSw0oCt46koKQbmwSIE11Kqq8MGtyW3W0ASpk/edit#slide=id.g61c66783ec_0_5)
and an example usage of `vtkPolyData` is as follows:

```
const polyData = vtkPolyData.newInstance()
Const vertices = new Float32Array(<xyz coords>)
Const polys = new Uint32Array(<poly definitions>)
polyData.getPoints().setData(vertices, 3)
polyData.getPolys().setData(polys);
```

It didn't work because the API seems to have changed (?) so I tried to do it this way:

```
const polyData = vtkPolyData.newInstance();
polyData.setVerts(vertices);
polyData.setPolys(polys);
```

Where `vertices` is `Float32Array` in format of `[x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, ...]`
and `polys` is `Uint32Array` in format of `[4, p1, p2, p3, p4, ...]` (my mesh uses only quads).

Then I connected it to the mapper:

```
// @ts-ignore
mapper.setInputData(meshSource);
```

Again `setInputData` wasn't declared but everything compiled anyway and there were no errors in the console. Unfortunately all I see is the background of the renderer. How can I display my custom data? Am I even going in right direction? I'm new to VTK.

Comment: Have you found a solution yet?